# Get current route name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

In laravel I can use the following to get the current name of the route in my blade template:

```
{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}
```

How can I do the same in Lumen?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, as Lumen uses [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) for routing, and not the Illuminate package that Laravel uses.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with:

```
list($found, $routeInfo, $params) = app('request')->route() ?: [false, [], []];

$routeName = isset($routeInfo['as']) ? $routeInfo['as'] : null;
```

Answer (score -1):

example:

```
<?php
  $method = Request::getMethod();
  $pathInfo = Request::getPathInfo();
  $currentRoute = $app->getRoutes()[$method.$pathInfo];

  echo $currentRoute['action']['as'];
?>
```

*tested version 5.0*